# ReactJS calculate state on change to components props as a result of parent re-render

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a sample app I am using to learn ReactJS.

It is nested set of master detail components. There is a list of cities, you click on a city and some details of the city are displayed along with a list of that city's bus routes. When you click on a bus route some (fairly pathetic :) detail of the bus route is displayed.

[Here is a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/map5vf94/10/)

The data is all contained in some arrays and there are two data helper functions, but this is just to make it simple and I will move the data to AJAX calls later.

If you look at the fiddle you will see that clicking on a city correctly updates the city detail and the list of bus routes and clicking on a bus route correctly displays the details of that bus route. The problem is that while clicking on a different city does update the city's bus routes, it does not display that city's first bus route.

**Here is the problem:** I think the `CityBusRoutes` component needs to recalc/ update its state but I dont know how/where to do this. `CityBusRoutes` is provided a `cityid` and then prepares a list of routes and I think should change its state to store the first route as the selected route. Initially the logical place seem to be in the render method, but this is obviously wrong.

Please feel free to offer any advice or links to docs about improving design etc.
Thanks.

Here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css"> li{ cursor: pointer; } </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="app"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.13.0/react.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.13.0/JSXTransformer.js"></script>
<script type="text/jsx">
var cityListing = [
    {id: 1, name: 'Rome', desc: 'Capital of Italy'}, 
    {id: 2, name: 'London', desc: 'Capital of UK'}, 
    {id: 3, name: 'Washington', desc: 'Capital of USA'}
];

var cityBuses = [
    {
        cityid: 1, 
        routes: [   
            {id: 707, desc: 'Rome to Beach'},
            {id: 717, desc: 'Beach to Rome'},
            {id: 708, desc: 'Rome to Naples'},
            {id: 718, desc: 'Naples to Rome'}
        ]
    },
    {
        cityid: 2,
        routes: [   
            {id: 801, desc: 'London to Beach'},
            {id: 811, desc: 'Beach to London'},
            {id: 802, desc: 'London to Manchester'},
            {id: 812, desc: 'Manchester to London'}
        ]
    },
    {
        cityid: 3,
        routes: [   
            {id: 901, desc: 'Washington to Beach'},
            {id: 911, desc: 'Beach to Washington'},
            {id: 902, desc: 'Washington to New York'},
            {id: 912, desc: 'New York to Washington'}
        ]
    }
];
function findCityBusRoutes(cityid){
    for(var i = 0; i < cityBuses.length; i++){
        if(cityBuses[i].cityid === cityid) return cityBuses[i];
    } 
    return null;
}
function findBusRouteDetails(routeid){
    var c, i, routes;
    if(typeof routeid !== 'number') routeid = parseInt(routeid);
    for(var c=0; c < cityBuses.length; c++){
        routes = cityBuses[c].routes;
        for(var i=0; i < routes.length; i++){
            if(routes[i].id === routeid){
                return "Take a scenic bus trip from " + routes[i].desc + '(' + routes[i].id + ')';
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}
var CityList = React.createClass({
    selectCity: function(citylistitem){
        this.setState( {selectedCity: citylistitem} );
    },
    getInitialState: function(){
        return {selectedCity: cityListing[0]};
    }, 
    render: function(){

        var listItems = cityListing.map(function(item){
            return <CityListItem key={item.id} data={item} onClick={this.selectCity} />
        }, this);  

        return(
            <div>
                <ul>{listItems}</ul>
                <CityDetail data={this.state.selectedCity} />
            </div>
        );

    }
});

var CityListItem = React.createClass({
    clickItem: function(e){
        this.props.onClick(this.props.data);
    },
    render: function(){
        return (
            <li onClick={this.clickItem}>{this.props.data.name}</li>
        )
    }
});

var CityDetail = React.createClass({
    render: function(){
        return(
            <div>
                <h3>City of {this.props.data.name}</h3>
                <p>{this.props.data.desc}</p>
                <CityBusRoutes data={this.props.data} />
            </div>
        );  
    }
});

var CityBusRoutes = React.createClass({
    clickBusRoute: function(e){     
        this.setState({ routeid: e.currentTarget.getAttribute('data-routeid')});
    },
    getInitialState: function(){
        var cityRoutes = findCityBusRoutes(this.props.data.id);
        return {routeid: cityRoutes.routes[0].id};
    },
    render: function(){
        var cityRoutes = findCityBusRoutes(this.props.data.id);

        var routeItems = cityRoutes.routes.map(function(route){
            return (
                <li data-routeid={route.id} onClick={this.clickBusRoute} >Route: {route.id}, Description: {route.desc}</li>
            )
        }, this);


        return(
            <div>
                <h3>{this.props.data.name} City Bus Routes</h3>
                <ul>{routeItems}</ul>
                <CityBusRouteDetail routeid={this.state.routeid}/>
            </div>
        );

    }   
});

var CityBusRouteDetail = React.createClass({
    render: function(){
        var rd = findBusRouteDetails(this.props.routeid);

        return(
            <div>
                <h5>Route Details</h5>
                <p>{rd}</p>
            </div>
        );
    }
});

React.render(<CityList />, document.getElementById('app'));
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok so I found the answer- Adding `componentWillReceiveProps()` method to my `CityBusRoutes` component is what I was looking for. Basically gives a place to calculate a new state when a components props change.

```
componentWillReceiveProps: function(nextProps){
    var cityRoutes = findCityBusRoutes(nextProps.data.id);
    this.setState({routeid: cityRoutes.routes[0].id});
}
```

[Heres the relevent React Docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html#updating-componentwillreceiveprops)

[Heres the working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/map5vf94/11/)

Still be very happy to receive any comments on above design

Answer (score 0):

componentWillMount & componentWillReceiveProps is a good way to deal with these problem