# How do I update an array for a React component?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, reactjs-flux, flux

I have found that **React** does not update a component when an element in the array is changed. Instead, a new array must be cloned and put in its place.

For example, I have an array of `_suggestedPeople`. When the UI element representing one of these people is clicked, I'd like to register this by calling `selectPerson`.

I would expect React to update after doing this:

```
selectPerson: function(personID, selected) {
    var person = _.find(_suggestedPeople, {id: personID});
    if (person) {
      person.selected = selected; 
    }
    return person;
  },
```

However, I end up doing this instead, which seems unnecessary:

```
selectPerson: function(personID, selected) {
    var index = _.findIndex(_suggestedPeople, {id: personID});
    var found = index !== -1;
    if (found) {
      var people = _.cloneDeep(_suggestedPeople);
      people[index].selected = selected;
      _suggestedPeople = people; 
    }
    return found;
  },
```

Is this the latter the correct way to update the array data of a React component? Or am I missing something?

Comment: Perhaps a different approach would fit better in the immutability paradigm. E.g. storing a reference to the selected person object in another property of the component instead of mutating the person objects.

Comment: Why not just trigger an update when a new selection occurs? React doesn't track properties of objects, so just setting selected of an object wouldn't work. For example, you could call [`forceUpdate`](http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-api.html#forceupdate).

Comment: Sorry I am finding it a little hard to follow your code snippets out of context, but I think you should store selected person in the components state (or the state of its parent depending on which component `selectPerson` is implemented in) and force a re render with a call to `this.setState({_suggestedPeople: people, selectedPerson: person})`. There is a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/map5vf94/11/ in the answer of this question which might be what you are trying to do- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30042657/reactjs-calculate-state-on-change-to-components-props-as-a-result-of-parent-re-r

Comment: Thank you. I did use `forceUpdate` at first, but felt I shouldn't have to, rather that there was an underlying problem I was circumventing. Maybe that's not the case. For this problem, I need to track multiple selections. Would you advocate a second list? `selectedPeople` array instead of `selectedPerson` object?

Answer (score 0):

You don't appear to be using React's built in state management. If you do, a middle ground between your two approaches of updating the state will work.  A component will re-render when it's state or properties change at all.

Edit: This code is outdated and not good practice. See updated jsfiddle below

Initialise the components state by implementing

```
getInitialState: function () {

   var whereverItComesFrom = [
      {id: 1, selected: false},
      {id: 2, selected: false}
   ];

   return {
       suggestedPeople: whereverItComesFrom
   }
}
```

your render method renders from this:

```
render: function () {
    var _this = this;
    var peeps = this.state.suggestedPeople.map(function(person, index){
        return <label key={index}><input type='checkbox' checked={person.selected} value={person.id} onChange={_this.handlePersonClick}/>{person.id}</label>;
    });

    return <div>{peeps}</div>;
},
```

handlePersonClick can be a merge of your methods:

```
handlePersonClick: function(e) {
    var selectedId = e.target.value;
    var checked = e.target.checked;
    var peeps = this.state.suggestedPeople;
    var index = _.findIndex(peeps, {id: selectedId});

    peeps[index].selected = checked;

    this.setState({suggestedPeople: peeps});
```

}

Edit: The above was very ill informed early days react for me. I've updated the fiddle link below and it should serve as a good basic example of solving this problem.

Full [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/85bbc73y/25/)

Comment: This won't do anything ... Modifying object in this matter won't trigger state change. You have to replace the whole array element.

Comment: @tomitrescak It works just fine because the call to `setState` forces a render. From the docs: `setState() will always trigger a re-render unless conditional rendering logic is implemented in shouldComponentUpdate()`.

Comment: Please don't ever do this, you're not supposed to mutate current state object. `setState` is not going to re-render your component immediately but you've immediately changed the state, this will cause really hard to find bugs!

Answer (score 0):

I think you are doing it wrong. You may come to react from angular js. Intead of using a function, To manipulate objects, Use **useState**. Local state with in component.

**Sample:**

```
const Comp = () => {
  const [selectedPerson, setSelectedPerson] = useState({});
  function onSelect(personID, selected) {
    var person = _.find(_suggestedPeople, { id: personID });
    if (person) {
      person.selected = selected;
    }
    setSelectedPerson(person);
  }
  return (
    <div>
      {selectedPerson.name}
      <select>
        <option onSelect={() => onSelect(id, "ssjsjs")}></option>
      </select>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

React setState is a shallow comparison, there is no need to use cloneDeep. react can be triggered to re-render only by changing the pointer to the address of `_suggestedPeople`. you can try like this:

```js
const App = () => {
  const [_suggestedPeople, setSuggestedPeople] = useState([
    {
      id: '1',
      name: 'A',
      selected: false,
    },
    {
      id: '2',
      name: 'B',
      selected: false,
    },
  ])
  const handleUserClick = (personID, selected) => {
    const person = _.find(_suggestedPeople, { id: personID })
    if (person) {
      person.selected = selected
    }
    setSuggestedPeople([..._suggestedPeople])
  }

  return (
    <div>
      {_suggestedPeople.map((user) => {
        return (
          <div
            onClick={() => {
              // selected or other things
              handleUserClick(user.id, true)
            }}
            className={user.selected ? 'selected' : ''}
          >
            {user.name}
          </div>
        )
      })}
    </div>
  )
}

export default App
```